# How to force calling to "onShowCustomView" method (iframe)

Tags: android, iframe, webview, youtube

How to force calling to "onShowCustomView" method when playing "Youtube" videos using iframe at Android 4.+

```
 mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, int requestedOrientation, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback){
            super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);   

        }
    });
```